# How to use addition information from geojson and d3js?

Tags: javascript, geojson

I am playing around a little bit with d3js, i created a GeoJson file from the Netherlands with basic statistic information, now i am able to render the card, but i don't get it how i can use the addition properties (IE showing the state name which is in a propertie: GM_CODE)

```
  d3.json("gemeente.json", function (data) {

      svg.selectAll("path").data(data.features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .style("fill", function () { return "#44aaee" })
    .on("mouseover", function (e) { d3.select(this).style("fill", "#5522aa") })
    .on("mouseout", function (e) { console.log(data.features); d3.select(this).style("fill", "#44aaee") })
  });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The properties in a geojson dataset are found at:
data.features.properties.
So if your property was "GM_CODE".
If would be data.features.properties.GM_CODE.

Used in a method it would be something like:

```
svg.selectAll("path").data(data.features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .style("fill", function () { return "#44aaee" })
    .text(function(d) { return d.properties.GM_CODE;})
```